# Magento 2 - Blank Theme not showing up good on mobile

Tags: magento2, mobile

I have a child theme that is exactly like the blank theme in Magento two. I have uploaded my product images. On some of the product pages, the site does not fill the size of the mobile screen. Its actually bigger, and the user needs to shrink the page to view the product page.

This is only happening with some products, so I assume it has something to do with some of the product images. For example, some of the product images when they load on mobile, are half on screen, and half off screen, so the user will have to shrink it to see the whole page.

Weird right? Only on some products. The rest of the pages are fine. I have used both PHP GP and Imagik to resize the catalog photos, but for some reason, some of them on mobile are making the screen size bigger than the mobile device.

And Google does not like this! Any advice?

Comment: pass the page URL having issue, can be fixed with some CSS tweaks

Comment: for secuirty, i would rather not share the website. But my other two magento websites work just fine. Just this one is having issues. I wouldnt want to tweak the CSS, because it should just work.